# What happened to Nautilus search

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

What happened to the search box that appears on a folder when you press ctrl+f? I used to be able to type and then navigate with the arrows (only between files that matched) and enter would open the file (not perform the search like in windows, which is what it does now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still there, but you do not have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.  Just open the folder in question and start typing.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> opens up another search dialogue where you can search inside folders and files.